# ExecutionEngineException was unhandled in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have done a fresh installation of Windows7, Visual Studio 2012 & SQL Server 2008 R2. Although my projects were working on my previous installation, those are not working anymore. All of my ASP.Net websites and web applications throwing the same exception. [image]

Comment: You may have more success if you spell the type of exception correctly in your question title...

Comment: @Liath, Thanks for informing. It was a typo, I haven't noticed while posting.